# scipy.optimize.curve_fit setting a "fixed" parameter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to approximate peaks in my data with Gaussian functions. This works well for strong peaks, but it is more difficult with weaker peaks. However, I think fixing a parameter (say, width of the Gaussian) would help with this. I know I can set initial "estimates" but is there a way that I can easily define a single parameter without changing the function I'm fitting to?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps you could add an example of your code (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help)?

Comment: Please add some data and some code, then it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Edit the Gaussian function you're fitting such that the parameter you want to hold constant no longer depends on the input arguments.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208634/fitting-only-one-paramter-of-a-function-with-many-parameters-in-python) helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "fix" a parameter of your fit function, you can just define a new fit function which makes use of the original fit function, yet setting one argument to a fixed value:

```
custom_gaussian = lambda x, mu: gaussian(x, mu, 0.05)
```

Here's a complete example of fixing `sigma` of a [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) to `0.05` (instead of optimal value `0.1`). Of course, this doesn't really make sense here because the algorithm has no problem in finding optimal values. Yet, you can see how `mu` is still found despite the fixed `sigma`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize 

def gaussian(x, mu, sigma):
    return 1 / sigma / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi) * np.exp(-(x - mu)**2 / 2 / sigma**2)

# Create sample data
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 200)
y = gaussian(x, 1, 0.1) + np.random.rand(*x.shape) - 0.5
plt.plot(x, y, label="sample data")

# Fit with original fit function
popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(gaussian, x, y)
plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, *popt), label="gaussian")

# Fit with custom fit function with fixed `sigma`
custom_gaussian = lambda x, mu: gaussian(x, mu, 0.05)
popt, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(custom_gaussian, x, y)
plt.plot(x, custom_gaussian(x, *popt), label="custom_gaussian")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: figure]

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this is helpful. Had to use hax. Curve_fit is pretty strict about what it takes.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def exp1(t,a1,tau1):
    #A1*exp(-t/t1)
    val=0.
    val=(a1*np.exp(-t/tau1))*np.heaviside(t,0)
    return val

def wrapper(t,*args):

    global hold
    global p0
    wrapperName='exp1(t,'
    for i in range(0, len(hold)):
        if hold[i]:
            wrapperName+=str(p0[i])
        else:
            if i%2==0:
                wrapperName+='args['+str(i)+']'
            else:
                wrapperName+='args'+str(i)+']'
        if i<len(hold):
            wrapperName+=','
    wrapperName+=')'

    return eval(wrapperName)

p0=np.array([1.5,500.])
hold=np.array([0,1])
p1=np.delete(p0,1)

timepoints = np.arange(0.,2000.,20.)
y=exp1(timepoints,1,1000)+np.random.normal(0, .1, size=len(timepoints))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(exp1, timepoints, y, p0=p0)
print 'unheld parameters:', popt, pcov

popt, pcov = curve_fit(wrapper, timepoints, y, p0=p1)
for i in range(0, len(hold)):
    if hold[i]:
        popt=np.insert(popt,i,p0[i])
yfit=exp1(timepoints,popt[0],popt[1])
pl.plot(timepoints,y,timepoints,yfit)
pl.show()
print 'hold parameters:', popt, pcov
```