# Fitting only 2 paramter of a function with many parameters in python

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, curve-fitting

I know there is a question 
[Fitting only one parameter of a function with many parameters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208634/fitting-only-one-paramter-of-a-function-with-many-parameters-in-python) 
but I have a little bit different situation. Problem with parameters of lambda function.

I am trying to fit Lorentz func

```
def lorentz(ph, A, xc, w, f0):
    return f0 + A * w**2 / (w**2 + (ph - xc)**2)
```

if I am fitting only one parameter (xc) its working good.

```
p1, p2, p3, p4 = params
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, xc: lorentz(x, p1, xc, p3, p4), abjd, adata, bounds=param_bounds)
```

But if I try to fit only 2 parameters (a, xc) it fails

```
p1, p2, p3, p4 = params    
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, a, xc: lorentz(x, a, xc, p3, p4), abjd, adata, bounds=param_bounds)
```

Error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "template.py", line 294, in <module>
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, a, xc: lorentz(x, a, xc, p3, p4), abjd, adata, bounds=param_bounds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 683, in curve_fit
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py", line 769, in least_squares
    f0 = fun_wrapped(x0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py", line 764, in fun_wrapped
    return np.atleast_1d(fun(x, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 455, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for all 4 parameters of Lorentz function

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lorentz(ph, A, xc, w, f0):
    return f0 + A * w**2 / (w**2 + (ph - xc)**2)

A, xc, w, f0 = 2,2,2,2  # true values
ph = np.linspace(-5, 10, 100)
y = lorentz(ph, A, xc, w, f0)    
ydata = y + 0.15 * np.random.normal(size=len(ph)) # sample data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lambda x, _A, _xc: lorentz(x, _A, _xc, w, f0), ph, ydata,bounds=([1,1], [3, 3]))
A, xc = popt # fitted values (only two)
```

You can easily add or remove parameters by putting them under the function lorentz() or with lambda

The result looks like this
[image]

Comment: can't understent. Can you write example for fitting 2 params ?

Comment: Yes, it works. thanks. The problem was in parameter `bounds=param_bounds` if I delete it its working good. But I realy need it

Comment: I'v modified again. It's working correctly with bounds.

Comment: I forgot to add bounds for second parameter. Its works from beginning, error mesage was not clear, I start to look for mistake in wrong place